# Symfony2 JMSI18nRoutingBundle - HTTP/HTTPS depends of locale

Tags: symfony, routes, twig, locale

I got a website, with several locales. Ex:

- fr_FR => https://mywebsite.fr
- en_FR => https://en.mywebsite.fr
- de_DE => https://mywebsite.de
- es_ES => http://mywebsite.es

I use JMSI18nRoutingBundle for that. Here my config:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    locales:
        - fr_FR
        - en_FR
        - de_DE
        - es_ES
    hosts:
        fr_FR: mywebsite.fr
        en_FR: en.mywebsite.fr
        es_ES: mywebsite.es
        de_DE: mywebsite.de
```

Some of my locales are in HTTPS, others no, like es_ES in this example.

In https://mywebsite.fr, I want to generate a link to the es_ES website, or inverse, generate https link to fr_FR in es_ES website.

Actually, I have a noSQL database with Redis, an hash foreach locale, with a value 'https' true or false, and I rewrite `getUrl` method from `RoutingExtension` to check HTTPS:

```
public function getUrl($name, $parameters = array(), $schemeRelative = false)

{
    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($name, $parameters, $schemeRelative ? UrlGeneratorInterface::NETWORK_PATH : UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);

    if (isset($parameters['_locale'])) {
        $locale = $parameters['_locale'];
    } else {
        $locale = $this->container->get('request')->getLocale();
    }

    // (localeGet will get the value of 'https' in Redis for this locale)
    if (false === $this->localeGet('https', $locale)) {
        $url = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $url);
    } else {
        $url = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $url);
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Is it a good way to do it, or have you a better idea ? It seems to be very ugly...

Comment: How do you manage the different domain for each language?

Comment: with JMSI18nRoutingBundle